# SQL Server: - Split a Single Record and divide the Amount Values and insert as Rows

Tags: sql-server

**PROBLEM**

Have been trying to work on this where for a particular From and ToDate, we need to take the difference between the Dates and the divide the Amount values by the difference and split the single record in Sample 1 to 5 rows in Resultant.

```
sr|      Number  |From_date|To_Date|Amount_1|Amount_2|Amount_3|Amount_4|Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |20140911204120|Jan-14   |May-14 |5000    |2500    |1000    |200     |A   
2 |20140911204122|Feb-14   |Apr-14 |6000    |3500    |2000    |1200    |R   
3 |20140911204124|Feb-14   |Jun-14 |7000    |4500    |3000    |2200    |R   
4 |20140911204126|Jul-14   |Sep-14 |8000    |5500    |4000    |3200    |R   
5 |20140911204128|Mar-14   |Aug-14 |9000    |6500    |5000    |4200    |A
```

**Resultant: - Record 1 after the process**

**So here in record 1** 
 1. We subtract the From Date and the To Date which gives us 5.

2. We then Divide the Amount Values by 5 and split them as 5 rows and add the
    row values for each individual month

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Sr|     Number   |Months  |Amount_1|Amount_2|Amount_3|Amount_4|Type
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |20140911204120|January |1000    |500     |200     |10      |A   
2 |20140911204120|February|1000    |500     |200     |10      |A   
3 |20140911204120|March   |1000    |500     |200     |10      |A   
4 |20140911204120|April   |1000    |500     |200     |10      |A   
5 |20140911204120|May     |1000    |500     |200     |10      |A
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of SQL Server you are using, so I did this with 2012, but it should probably work on 2008 too if needed (although the`TRY_CONVERT`used for parsing dates has to be changed). Also, I'm guessing your sample desired output is wrong for`Amount_4`as 200/5=40 not 10.

Note that all the divisions are integer which meant potential loss of precision - if you need more precise values you have to cast to some appropriate type (decimal or float).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f13dd/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
    ([sr] int, [Number] bigint, [From_date] varchar(6), [To_date] varchar(6), [Amount_1] int, [Amount_2] int, [Amount_3] int, [Amount_4] int, [Type] varchar(1));

INSERT INTO YourTable ([sr], [Number], [From_date], [To_date], [Amount_1], [Amount_2], [Amount_3], [Amount_4], [Type])
VALUES
    (1, 20140911204120, 'Jan-14', 'May-14', 5000, 2500, 1000, 200, 'A'),
    (2, 20140911204122, 'Feb-14', 'Apr-14', 6000, 3500, 2000, 1200, 'R'),
    (3, 20140911204124, 'Feb-14', 'Jun-14', 7000, 4500, 3000, 2200, 'R'),
    (4, 20140911204126, 'Jul-14', 'Sep-14', 8000, 5500, 4000, 3200, 'R'),
    (5, 20140911204128, 'Mar-14', 'Aug-14', 9000, 6500, 5000, 4200, 'A');
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH cte (Date, To_date, [Number], [Amount_1], [Amount_2], [Amount_3], [Amount_4], [Type]) AS
(
    SELECT 
        Date = TRY_PARSE(From_date AS DATE), 
        To_date = TRY_PARSE(To_date AS DATE), 
        [Number], 
        [Amount_1], 
        [Amount_2], 
        [Amount_3], 
        [Amount_4], 
        [Type]
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Date), 
        To_date, 
        [Number], 
        [Amount_1], 
        [Amount_2], 
        [Amount_3], 
        [Amount_4], 
        [Type]
    FROM cte    
    WHERE Date < To_date
)

SELECT 
    Sr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Number, Date),
    Number, 
    Months,
    Amount_1 = Amount_1/c,
    Amount_2 = Amount_2/c, 
    Amount_3 = Amount_3/c,
    Amount_4 = Amount_4/c,
    Type
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Number, 
        Months = DATENAME(MONTH, Date), 
        Date,
        Amount_1,
        Amount_2, 
        Amount_3,
        Amount_4,
        Type, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE Number = c.Number GROUP BY Number) AS c
    FROM cte c
) a
ORDER BY Number, Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f13dd/2/0)**:

```
| SR |         NUMBER |    MONTHS | AMOUNT_1 | AMOUNT_2 | AMOUNT_3 | AMOUNT_4 | TYPE |
|----|----------------|-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|------|
|  1 | 20140911204120 |   January |     1000 |      500 |      200 |       40 |    A |
|  2 | 20140911204120 |  February |     1000 |      500 |      200 |       40 |    A |
|  3 | 20140911204120 |     March |     1000 |      500 |      200 |       40 |    A |
|  4 | 20140911204120 |     April |     1000 |      500 |      200 |       40 |    A |
|  5 | 20140911204120 |       May |     1000 |      500 |      200 |       40 |    A |
|  1 | 20140911204122 |  February |     2000 |     1166 |      666 |      400 |    R |
|  2 | 20140911204122 |     March |     2000 |     1166 |      666 |      400 |    R |
|  3 | 20140911204122 |     April |     2000 |     1166 |      666 |      400 |    R |
|  1 | 20140911204124 |  February |     1400 |      900 |      600 |      440 |    R |
|  2 | 20140911204124 |     March |     1400 |      900 |      600 |      440 |    R |
|  3 | 20140911204124 |     April |     1400 |      900 |      600 |      440 |    R |
|  4 | 20140911204124 |       May |     1400 |      900 |      600 |      440 |    R |
|  5 | 20140911204124 |      June |     1400 |      900 |      600 |      440 |    R |
|  1 | 20140911204126 |      July |     2666 |     1833 |     1333 |     1066 |    R |
|  2 | 20140911204126 |    August |     2666 |     1833 |     1333 |     1066 |    R |
|  3 | 20140911204126 | September |     2666 |     1833 |     1333 |     1066 |    R |
|  1 | 20140911204128 |     March |     1500 |     1083 |      833 |      700 |    A |
|  2 | 20140911204128 |     April |     1500 |     1083 |      833 |      700 |    A |
|  3 | 20140911204128 |       May |     1500 |     1083 |      833 |      700 |    A |
|  4 | 20140911204128 |      June |     1500 |     1083 |      833 |      700 |    A |
|  5 | 20140911204128 |      July |     1500 |     1083 |      833 |      700 |    A |
|  6 | 20140911204128 |    August |     1500 |     1083 |      833 |      700 |    A |
```

Comment: We will be using 2014. Should work i guess. Will try it and mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can join your table with a month table, to expend your data, that will be more efficient than recursive query.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11780/19)

```
;WITH months (month,month_name) AS
(select number,DATENAME(MONTH,cast(rtrim(20140000+number*100+1) as datetime))
    from master..spt_values
    where number between 1 and 12 AND TYPE='P'
)
SELECT     Sr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Number, month),
    Number, 
    Month_name,
    Amount_1 = Amount_1/(datediff(month,TRY_PARSE(from_date AS DATE),TRY_PARSE(to_date AS DATE))+1),
    Amount_2 = Amount_2/(datediff(month,TRY_PARSE(from_date AS DATE),TRY_PARSE(to_date AS DATE))+1), 
    Amount_3 = Amount_3/(datediff(month,TRY_PARSE(from_date AS DATE),TRY_PARSE(to_date AS DATE))+1),
    Amount_4 = Amount_4/(datediff(month,TRY_PARSE(from_date AS DATE),TRY_PARSE(to_date AS DATE))+1),
    Type
FROM YourTable
JOIN Months
on month between  datepart(month,TRY_PARSE(from_date AS DATE)) and datepart(month,TRY_PARSE(to_date AS DATE))
```